# How to make path for java to read input.txt file?

Tags: java

I trying to read a file, but I always get a NullPointerException. Somebody know what may be the problem? I get NullPointerException at java.io.Reader, java.io.BufferedReader, at elte.hu.eltecom.file.FileManager.readGraph and at elte.hu.eltecom.Main.main

### Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //   if (args.length == 0) return;

    FileManager fm = new FileManager();
    Manager manager;
    manager = fm.readGraph("szia");
    User user = manager.getUserById(3);

    if  (user instanceof AdminUser){
        ((AdminUser) user).kickUser(manager.getUserById(1));
        ((AdminUser) user).kickUser(manager.getUserById(2));

        User grabowski = new User("Grabowski", Language.HUN);

        manager.createUser(grabowski);

        manager.linkUsers(grabowski,user);

    }
    fm.writeGraph(manager,args[0]);
}
```

---

### File Manager:

```
static public Manager readGraph(String s) {

    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(s + "/input.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String sCurrentLine = null;

    try {
        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    int x = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);

    Graph graph = null;
    graph = initGraph(x);   
    Manager manager = null;
    manager = new Manager(graph);

    int temp = 0;
    boolean lineLeft = true;

    try {
        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    User users[] = new User[x];

    while(lineLeft){
        if (temp < x){
            String line[] =  sCurrentLine.split(" ", 2);
            Language language = Language.valueOf(line[0]);
            User user;
            String name = line[1];
            if (line[1].contains("#")){
                name = name.substring(1);
                user= manager.createAdminUser(name, language);
            }
            else{
                user = manager.createUser(name, language);
            }
            users[temp] = user;
        }
        else {
            String line[] = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length ; i++){
                if (Boolean.valueOf(line[i])){
                    graph.linkNodes(users[temp-x], users[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
        if ( (sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) == null)
            lineLeft = false;

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        temp++;
    }

    return manager;
}
}
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the NPE ? Have you tried using debugger ?

Comment: Try printing the stack trace at `fr = new FileReader(s + "/input.txt");` line's catch block. Also, paste the exception in your question.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
try {
        fr = new FileReader(s + "/input.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
```

You just wrote: "Read file 'whatever', if the file is not found ignore it. 
At this point `fr` is null and you pass it as input to `BufferedReader` without checking if it is null or not.

Either write a nullcheck before instantiating the `BufferedReader` or do something else if the file is not found.

Ignoring exceptions in that way is very dangerous and you code will not be reliable.

Another suggestion, `String s` has very poor readability, try to give a better name (`path` or `appDir` or whatever makes it understandable to a reader without the need to go back to read the full code).